# Dynamic programming algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, counting

I'm going through this textbook trying to solve some algorithms to better my skills and I'm currently stuck at this problem:

[image]

The chapter is on dynamic programming and I'm really just having trouble starting the problem since I don't know how to approach these types of problems. Can anyone help me solve it or point me to an existing algorithm that's similar?

Comment: Often with DP a useful first step is, counterintuitively, to make the problem *more* specific: Can you calculate the maximum number of lollies you can get *starting from some given day i*?  (Important: notice I said "starting from day i", not "starting from day i and taking that day's lollies".  Even if you start on day i, you still have the option to wait one or more days.)  Call this f(i).  Can you write an expression for f(i) in terms of other values of f()?  Hint: it must be the maximum of whatever choices you can make on day i...

Comment: what programming language do you need a solution in?

Comment: The answer doesn't have to be in any language. An algorithmic pseudocode solution would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is the solution of the following recursive formula:

```
f(i) = max{ l_i + f(i+k_i) , f(i+1) }
f(x) = 0 : for all x > n
```

The solution for the problem is the solution of `f(1)`.

Explanation: For each day, you can either "skip" this day, and check the next day (or the one after it, ... , this is done by invoking `f(i+1)`) - or take lollies, and then you have the option to come back only after `k_i` days - meaning you add the solution of `f(i+k_i)` .